# How to retrieve count of values in LINQ One to Many relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have `Book` Entity that contains field representing its `Readers`

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int Date { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public Author? Author { get; set; }

    public string Cover { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public List<User> UsersMarked { get; set; } = new();

    public BookGenre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

For one of the requests I make I transform this entity into its DTO that does not have the List of Users but it contains `int` representing the count of `Users` that have marked the book.

```
public record BookPageDto(
    string Title,
    int Date,
    int ReadersCount,
    string Cover,
    BookGenre Genre,
    string Description,);
```

Right now I am requesting this data by including entire List of Users to it.

```
public async Task<Book?> GetBookByTitleAsync(string title)
{
        return await _context.Books
            .Include(b=>b.UsersMarked)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Title.ToLower() == title);
}
```

This operation loads the `UsersMarked` list into memory to eventually get its count. As I understand it makes my code memory inefficient, because I don't really need the whole list but only its count.

Since I can't use `Include` statement like this

```
_context.Books.Include(b=>b.UsersMarked.Count())
```

because it response with an error. I would like to know how can I get the count of `UsersMarked` besides adding the `Count` field directly to my `Book` Entity.

Hope I got it clear.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try : _context.Books.UsersMarked.Count()

Comment: @jdweng you cannot access ```UsersMarked``` like this. Because ```_context.Books``` is a DbSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Projection Query](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/projection-queries-in-ef-core/)

```
var bookQuery = _context.Books
    .Where(b => b.Title.ToLower() == title)
    .Select(b => new BookPageDto
    {
        //...
        ReadersCount = b.UsersMarked.Count(),
        //...
    });
```

---

Or just separating the query into two steps to retrieve the count once you have the book id in hand:

```
var book = await bookQuery.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (book != null)
{
    book.ReadersCount = await _context.Users
        .CountAsync(u => u.UsersMarked.Any(b => b.Id == book.Id));
}
```